# Install Android L on Nexus 5 which is rooted

Tags: android, nexus-5, rooted-device

I have rooted my Nexus 5 long back. Today I received a notification asking me to install Android L from play store. When I downloaded it and restarted for installation it is taking me to the team win recovery project screen with out installing the Android L OS. How should I ask the device to forcefully install the new OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images link helped me. Here you can restore your device back to original firmware.